# Why is onStartInputView() called when the device is locked?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime, android-input-method

I am writing a custom IME and there's something I don't understand in its [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method#InputMethodLifecycle).

`onStartInputView()` and `onFinishInputView()` are supposed to be called when the keyboard view is displayed and destroyed, respectively. They're also called if the user changes app or text field while the soft keyboard is up. That's fine.

They weird case is that:

1. **Given the soft keyboard is currently shown** and I'm typing text (for instance, in my SMS app)
2. **When I lock my device (turn the screen off)**
3. Then I see a weird successions of calls:

```
onFinishInputView(finishingInput=true)
onStartInputView(editorInfo, restarting=false)
onFinishInputView(finishingInput=true)
onStartInputView(editorInfo, restarting=false)
```

`onStartInputView()` is the last call, so from the IME perspective the keyboard view is "visible" even though my device is locked (screen off).

My custom IME needs to know precisely when the keyboard is not displayed anymore (for instance to stop some background processing, or send a *session close* event): how can I do that since it seems I can't rely on `onStartInputView()`?

Thanks!

Comment: So far, a workaround (but not a solution) I've found is to check whether the screen is on when onStartInputView is called, via `isScreenOn = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 20 ? powerManager.isScreenOn() : powerManager.isInteractive())`

Comment: you're testing your app on Android P or Q?